# Least square fit of polynomial with constrained coefficients

Tags: convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, least-squares, constraints

I would like to perform least square regression with a polynomial:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1\dots N} ( p(x_i) -y_i )^2 \stackrel{!}{=} min ,
\end{equation}
$(x_i,y_i)$ the observations,
\begin{equation}
p(x) = \sum_{j=0\dots 6} a_jx^j 
\end{equation}
the sixth degree polynomial, and finally the constraints
\begin{equation}
a_0 > 0, a_1 < 0, a_2 > 0, a_3 < 0, a_4 > 0, a_5 < 0, a_6 > 0,
\end{equation}
which determine to some extent the shape of the polynomial.

In a quadratic program with constraints this means, that the parameters $a_i$ would appear in the objective function as well as in the contraints. How can I handle this?

Comment: This should not make any problem if you have an optimizer able to handle bound constaints (this is probably the easiest case). I wrote many years ago a specific program for this. It is in Fortran but still works. If you want, send me a .TXT file with your data. If it works properly for you, I could give it. My e-mail address is in my profile. I shall probably need to make some cleaning work to make it as user-driendly as possible.

Answer (score 0):

(more a comment)

If you do a Google search
for your title,
you get many hits,
though most of them
do not seem to satisfy
your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Browsing related problems meanwhile I found the following idea:
Use the polynomial
\begin{equation}
p(x)= \sum_{j=0\dots 6} a_j^2(-x)^j
\end{equation}
With the R function *optim* this can be solved. Or, alternatively, after taking partial derivatives with respect to the $a_j$, the resulting system of equations can be solved numerically.